# VMProtect keygen, turn off the anti-debugging

Tags: debugging, anti-debugging, x64dbg, virtual-machines, vmprotect

who faced with VMProtect? I just found on the Internet crackme and decided to grunt it, but unfortunately not that good of it did not work out, as the message about prevention of debugging climbed out. the whole point of the problem is to find out the constant password and I decided as usual I do in such cases turn off the anti-debugging and I'm looking for a password, so I put the check for the `IsDebuggerPresent` system functions, `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` and when they were called by the simply return value set 0, surprisingly did not help. Can you please tell us how to avoid debugger detection?

P.S. Everything for the sole purpose of education

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like [ScyllaHide](https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide) to hide your debugger while you still don‘t know the method they use to detect you.

Comment: Well it's too easy :-)